# Cannot enter password in lock screen dialog after long suspend

Tags: password, suspend, lock-screen, switch-user

I am currently using Ubuntu 13.10 and recently I've noticed that after my ASUS K56CB laptop goes into suspend mode, and is left like that for a long time (about an hour or more), the password input field in the lock screen dialogue seems to be inactive (greyed out) after I've resumed the session, restricting me from entering my password. Clicking on it using the mouse pointer doesn't bring it into focus either. The only work around is to click the switch user button and then re-enter my password in Ubuntu's main login screen. I know this isn't a major issue but this extra step really annoys me especially when I know that it works for short suspends. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you use any IME? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method_editor

Comment: Is it maybe this bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1311316 It is reported for Ubuntu 14.04, but the description looks similar (check the screenshot in comment #2).